# How can I mathematically prove this?

Tags: optimization, convex-optimization, nonlinear-optimization, non-convex-optimization

How can I mathematically prove that **P1** and **P2** will have the same value of $\eta$ at optimality? Although it seems clear from the intuition. I am looking for proof in the language of mathematics, not in English.

**P1**
\begin{align}
\max_{\eta,x_1,x_2} \eta\\
\eta\leq \dfrac{x_1}{x_2}\\
\eta \leq x_2\\
0\leq x_1\leq A\\
0\leq x_2\leq A
\end{align}
**P2**
\begin{align}
\max_{\eta,x_2} \eta\\
\eta\leq \dfrac{A}{x_2}\\
\eta \leq x_2\\
0\leq x_2\leq A
\end{align}

Comment: We should have $x_2>0$, because it occurs in the denominators.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**P1.** We have $\eta^2\le \frac {x_1}{x_2}x_2=x_1\le A$, so $\eta\le \sqrt{A}$ and the equality is achieved when $\eta=x_2=\sqrt{x_1}=\sqrt{A}$.

**P2.** We have $\eta^2\le \frac A{x_2}x_2=A$, so $\eta\le \sqrt{A}$ and the equality is achieved when $\eta=x_2=\sqrt{A}$.